# Is there a shorter code to join the keys and values for a dictionary?

Tags: python

Is there a shorter or better snippet that accomplishes the following:

```
>>> h = { 'apple' : 'ipad' , 'amazon': 'kindle' }
>>> [' '.join(item) for item in zip( h.keys(), h.values())]
[ 'apple ipad', 'amazon kindle' ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> [' '.join(item) for item in h.iteritems()]
['amazon kindle', 'apple ipad']

>>> map(' '.join, h.iteritems())
['amazon kindle', 'apple ipad']
```

But avoid using `map()` these days. And list comprehensions if you can help it.

Comment: `map()` has changed in 3.x. And genexs exist.

Comment: Avoid list comprehensions?  But they're so awesome

Comment: @Lionel the point is to use generator comprehensions instead where possible. List comprehensions imply that an eagerly-evaluated list is required.